# Read pdf using java

Tags: java, heap-memory, itextpdf

i have a problem with reading PDF file content in java using **itextpdf.jar** ,

if i read a **small sized(5-15MB) PDF file** means its working well, it is possible to read it's contents

but when i read **large sized(200MB) PDF file** means its showing **Run time exception** like following

```
enter code hereException in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2786)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:94)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.InputStreamToArray(RandomAccessFileOrArray.java:213)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.<init>(RandomAccessFileOrArray.java:203)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:235)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:246)
at general.FileStreamClose.main(FileStreamClose.java:28)
```

Java Result: 1`enter code here`

any solution for this , how to increase heap size in tomcat

Comment: increase heap memory using flag -Xmx, google it

Comment: What is the OS you're using?

Comment: @vikasing we can increase the heap memory by -Xmx, but how can we do it in tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tune your Java Application Runtime settings:

maximize heap size to high value with `-Xmx` say 500M

tune `-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio` and `-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio` to make sure  that the application will not becomes irresponsive when consuming lot of memory when the heap reduces.

Comment: Thanks for your point, if it is **java application** we can set it via **command prompt**, My question is for **web application** where to configure this settings.

Comment: in web-application these will be runtime parameters for the container/server

Comment: sorry i don't get exactly i mean which place, XML name

Comment: which application / web server you are using ?

Comment: right-click on the project and select "Properties" and then "Run"; there you can set the VM options appropriately

Answer (score 0):

to increase heap size for tomcat you'll have to set the evnirenment variable `JAVA_OPTS` and have it contain the `-Xmx` option for example `-Xmx512m`

here is a sample script how you can run tomcat

```
@echo off
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33
set CATALINA_HOME=C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0
set JAVA_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xmx512m -server
call %CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat run
```

Answer (score 0):

for additional info, as far as i know, if your machine is 32 bit increase xmx and xms heap size will limited around 1k++. If you need more than that you need to install java 64 bit (of course in 64 machine and 64 OS).